Recommendation Needed for Apps that require License
Question: Is there a way to find out if an app for software development or similar is free or it requires a license ? I would like to create a list of those apps.
I have a list of over 2000 in PowerBI, I would like to create couple of columns of FREE and Require License and add the information.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.
